# Code that works for a form control doesn't work for ActiveX control

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, macros

First time poster in StackOverflow (but not stackexchange) so please let me know if I can clarify or make any formatting changes. Thank you.

Try as I might, I can't find the answer to this question. I suspect it's due to a lack of understanding when it comes to the basics of VBA. I have knowledge of VBA, but little understanding. That being said, here's the problem.

I've set up a form control Combo Box linked to a macro. I've set the input range to a list of hyperlinks in a different sheet and named the range "Hyperlinks". Each hyperlink is to a different sheet in the workbook. I've set the cell link to a blank sell adjacent to the hyperlinks and named it "Linked_Cell." A picture is below.

[Form Control View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCPuy.png)

The macro code is as follows

```
Sub DropDown10_Change()
HyperLink_Index = Range("Linked_cell")
  If Range("HyperLinks").Offset(HyperLink_Index - 1, 0).Hyperlinks(1).Name   <> "" Then
       Range("HyperLinks").Offset(HyperLink_Index - 1, 0).Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
End If
End Sub
```

This automatically moves someone to the sheet they select when they select that sheet from the drop-down menu.

I would like to use an Active X combo box instead of a form control for all the obvious reasons (resize text, etc.) However, I can't get it to work.

I've set "ListFillRange" to "Hyperlinks" and linked cell to "Linked_cell" and entered the same macro code. It looks like this:

[View of Active X Combo Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcGug.png)

When I select from the drop down in the Active X Combo box I receive run time error 1004: "Method 'range' of object '_worksheet' failed." I've verified that my named ranges are correct and the code returns no such error when it's in a macro linked to a form control.

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

UPDATE: Fixed the Range error by updating the code to the following

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim HyperLink_Index As Range
Set HyperLink_Index = Sheets("SheetList").Range("Linked_Cell")
  If Sheets("SheetList").Range("HyperLinks").Offset(HyperLink_Index - 1, 0).Hyperlinks(1).Name <> "" Then
       Sheets("SheetList").Range("HyperLinks").Offset(HyperLink_Index - 1, 0).Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
End If
End Sub
```

I now receive a Type Mismatch error on the beginning of the IF statement. I don't see the error and still have no idea why this behavior doesn't appear for identical macro code linked to a form control.

P.S. Sorry, I don't mean to turn StackOverflow in to my personal debugging team, so the main question I have is "Why is the behavior different between a macro and active x code?"

UPDATE 2: Found a fix. Was using the wrong index. The fix is below. Leaving it here in case someone else can find it useful.

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()

If ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
       Sheets("SheetList").Range("Hyperlinks").Hyperlinks(ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Before the offending `If`, put the line `Debug.Print HyperLink_Index`. I suspect that it isn't what you think it is. Perhaps you don't have the correct named range. Maybe it is on a different sheet?

Comment: Thank you @JohnColeman. You led me to the fix! I've updated my question and posted it. My code was far more complicated than it needed to be and I was using the wrong index (as you suspected).

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix. Was using the wrong index. The fix is below. Leaving it here in case someone else can find it useful.

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()

If ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
   Sheets("SheetList").Range("Hyperlinks").Hyperlinks(ComboBox1.ListIndex +1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True

End If
End Sub
```